# How to redirect a page into file?

Tags: redirect, urls

I have used Redirect 301 "/page" "/uploades/file.pdf"

we are using wordpress, When I try to call the url it is redirects to {domain}/uploades/file.pdf/

a '/' append at end of the URL, so that it returns 404. Can anyone help resolve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Recommend and currently use **Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin**
https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

**Request URL**  **Destination URL**

`/page/`  `http://example.com/uploades/file.pdf`

Comment: Be careful. The plugin that you have recommended has negative comments that say it allows malicious code to destroy wordpress website. It says it contains malicious code, injects spam and adware.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit your .htaccess and your ready to dive straight in this code should do it.

```
RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and check again

Comment: can you explain the answer plz